# Magento 2 Custom Module admin form category tree

Tags: magento2, category-tree

How to get Magento 2 category tree  in Custom Module admin form.

I din't use UI Component I am using **Main.php**

like this i am adding

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'label',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'name',
                'label' => __('name'),
                'title' => __('name'),
                'note' => __('name'),
                'required' => true
            ]
        );
```

here how to add like this

[image]

Comment: Please check this article https://belvg.com/blog/a-category-chooser-in-magento-2-backend.html

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94392/in-magento-2-adminhtml-form-with-multiselect-how-to-show-previous-answers-as-sel

do you have checked this article

Comment: I already checked  but i want Tree view only

Answer (score 1):

Firstly add a field in your ui-form:

```
<field name="custom" component="Namespce_Modulename/js/select-category" sortOrder="20" formElement="select">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>//to add filter in select-ui
        <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>//select multiple or not
        <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>//to show checkboxes
        <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<settings>
    <required>true</required>
    <validation>
        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
    </validation>
    <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
    <label translate="true">Select Category</label>//label to Field
    <dataScope>data.custom</dataScope>//To map
    <componentType>field</componentType>
    <listens>
        <link name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData">setParsed</link>
    </listens>
</settings>
<formElements>
    <select>
        <settings>
            <options class="Namespace\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Form\Category\Options"/>
        </settings>
    </select>
</formElements>
```

Now create Js file to map the field's value:

Namespace_Modulename/view/adminhtml/web/js/select-category.js

```
define([
'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select'
], function (Select) {
'use strict';
return Select.extend({
    /**
     * Parse data and set it to options.
     *
     * @param {Object} data - Response data object.
     * @returns {Object}
     */
    setParsed: function (data) {
        var option = this.parseData(data);
        if (data.error) {
            return this;
        }
        this.options([]);
        this.setOption(option);
        this.set('newOption', option);
    },
    /**
     * Normalize option object.
     *
     * @param {Object} data - Option object.
     * @returns {Object}
     */
    parseData: function (data) {
        return {
            value: data.category.entity_id,
            label: data.category.name
        };
    }
});
});
```

Create a file to get options to display:

Namespace\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Form\Category\Options.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Form\Category;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory as      CategoryCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

/**
* Options tree for "Categories" field
*/
class Options implements OptionSourceInterface
{

protected $categoryCollectionFactory;

/**
 * @var RequestInterface
 */
protected $request;

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $categoryTree;

/**
 * @param CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
 * @param RequestInterface $request
 */
public function __construct(
    CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
    RequestInterface $request
) {
    $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    $this->request = $request;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function toOptionArray()
{
    return $this->getCategoryTree();
}

/**
 * Retrieve categories tree
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getCategoryTree()
{
    if ($this->categoryTree === null) {
        $collection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');

        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $categoryId = $category->getEntityId();
            if (!isset($categoryById[$categoryId])) {
                $categoryById[$categoryId] = [
                    'value' => $categoryId
                ];
            }
            $categoryById[$categoryId]['label'] = $category->getName();
        }
        $this->categoryTree = $categoryById;
    }
    return $this->categoryTree;
}
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I used your solution for display categories in my admin form but it showing errors.       
Element 'argument': This element is not expected.
Line: 5

Verify the XML and try again.

Answer (score 0):

**Working for me, but I edited two lines of code in `Options.php` file**

> 1) use `Magento\Catalog\.. instead of Magento\Category`
>
> 2) `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name'); instead of
>   $collection->addNameToSelect();`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add all of these files in order to add Category Tree in your custom grid/module. Just add the following in  view/adminhtml/ui_component/form_edit.xml file of your custom module

```
<field name="category_id" component="Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category" sortOrder="20" formElement="select">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <required>true</required>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
            <label translate="true">Select Category</label>
            <dataScope>data.category_id</dataScope>
            <componentType>field</componentType>
            <listens>
                <link name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData">setParsed</link>
            </listens>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

[image: Category Tree]